# saving to the database in an Asynchronous task. Android

Tags: android, asynchronous, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter, listactivity

So what I am trying to do is to insert into the database. 
I found the following code online at

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

What is important for me is shown in the following block

```
ArrayAdapter<Comment> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Comment>) getListAdapter();
Comment comment = null;
switch (view.getId()) {
case R.id.add:
  String[] comments = new String[] { "Cool", "Very nice", "Hate it" };
  int nextInt = new Random().nextInt(3);
  // Save the new comment to the database
  comment = datasource.createComment(comments[nextInt]);
  adapter.add(comment);
```

As you can see, the code is using an arrayAdapter and in order to define it uses the method

```
getListAdapter()
```

Which a method from the class

```
ListActivity
```

So you can easily guess that this class is extended as following

```
public class TestDatabaseActivity extends ListActivity
```

Now we reach my problem. I am trying to do the same but in a synchronous activity, however in order to implement a synchronous task you need to extend another class as following

```
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>
```

What I tried is to change the relationship between my class UserLoginTask and the class ListActivity from isA relationship to hasA relationship as shown below

```
//hasA relationship isA relationship
ListActivity listActiity;
```

So now that block of data will be edited as following

```
ArrayAdapter<Comment> adapter =    (ArrayAdapter<Comment>) ((ListActivity) listAdapter).getListAdapter();
// Save the new comment to the database
comment = datasource.createComment(comments[nextInt]);
adapter.add(comment);
```

However this result in a null pointer exception which refers to that line

```
adapter.add(comment);
```

Any suggestions ? and thanks in advance

Comment: is your asynctask in a seperate class ?

Comment: you adapter is null because you never call setListAdapter.

Comment: @Raghunandan no it is in the same class

Comment: @njzk2 sorry but what you mean by that ?

Comment: `(ArrayAdapter<Comment>) getListAdapter();` requires that you previously called something like `setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Comment>(...));`

Comment: @njzk2 Well make sense.
But there is an issue of the need to extend two classes

How to solve it

Comment: i don't understand. this is the issue

Comment: @njzk2 As I mentioned above, I already did extend another class.
That made me unable to extend the class ListActivity.

So what I did is to define an object of that class
 private ListActivity listActivity;

and then I used that object as following
     listActivity.setListAdapter(adapter);

However this gave me a null pointer exception at that line